# how do I document an R Reference Class?

Tags: r, documentation, rd, reference-class

how do I document the use of member functions of a reference class?

if I write a `Rd` file with a `\usage` block, how do I avoid the `WARNING`

```
Functions/methods with usage in documentation object 'XmlDoc' but not in code:
  $ new
```

I'd expect the `\usage` block to allow me write things like:

```
obj <- ClassName$new(par1, par2, ...)
obj$method1(oth1, ...)
```

and then I'd document the parameters in the `\arguments` block.

If I do this, `R CMD check` complains with

```
Assignments in \usage in documentation object 'ClassName':
```

and does not recognize the methods as code objects I need document.

as of now, I am writing `Rd` files without the `\usage` block and writing the above code in the `\examples` block, but then I have no place to document arguments and this way the `check` has very little to check actually. Since I'm not satisfied with this, I'm now asking the community about the current common practice.

Comment: I don't know whether this is also the case for reference classes, but S3 classes you would use `\alias` to address this same problem.

Comment: That's not how usage blocks work unfortunately.  Have you read the help about the built-in reference class documentation?

Comment: @hadley: I thought I had, but obviously I missed the `\S4method` item thing.  to which documentation do you refer, that describes it?

Comment: In "?ReferenceClasses" search for help.

Comment: yes, that I did, but there is no occurrence of the string `S4method` in that page. (I'm using R version 2.13.0 (2011-04-13))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if I understood correctly, Reference Classes methods **are** S4 methods, so [documenting S4 classes and methods](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Documenting-S4-classes-and-methods) applies.

to make this answer a bit more self contained, here is what I am doing in the case of the `Logger` class in the `logging.oo` package.

this is the code I wanted to document, with some omissis [...].

```
Logger <- setRefClass("Logger",
                      fields=list(name = "character"),
                      methods=list(
                        setLevel = function(newLevel) { [...] },
                        getLevel = function() { [...] },
                        addHandler = function(...) { [...] },
```

this is the corresponding content of the .Rd file(s):

```
\alias{\S4method{new}{Logger}}
\alias{\S4method{setLevel}{Logger}}
\alias{\S4method{getLevel}{Logger}}
\alias{\S4method{addHandler}{Logger}}
[...]
\usage{
\S4method{new}{Logger}(name)
\S4method{setLevel}{Logger}(newLevel)
\S4method{getLevel}{Logger}()
\S4method{addHandler}{Logger}(...)
```

while in the NAMESPACE file I just indicate I'm exporting the Logger class, I don't specify its methods: all are automatically exported.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if it's the Right Way, but what I've done is to have a **Methods** section and then put the method documentation in an interior **describe**.

Comment: ok, but then more precisely: inside of the `\usage` section, I can add `\S4method` entries.  for each S4method I document I need to add an `\alias` entry.  the entries in the `\alias` do not need the list of parameters.

Comment: If I understand you correct then you're right.  For a method "foo", I tend to make an alias for "foo" and "foo.class-method" where foo is the name of the method and class is the name of the class.  Again, I can't say that this is the Right Way, just how I have done them.

Comment: Jeoff, check my other answer, does it match what you are also doing?

Comment: is there any way to split method definition in seperate files. Like `initializr.R` or `populate.R`?