# Roxygen2 - how to @export reference class generator?

Tags: r, package, roxygen2, reference-class, roxygen

For instance, say I have the following package called `Test` and I want to export class `A`:

```
# In /R/Test.R:
#' @docType package
#' @import methods
#' @exportClass A
A <- setRefClass("A", methods = list(foo = identity))
```

However, after building and loading, I get the following error when using `A`'s generator:

```
> library(Test)
> A()$foo(1)
Error: could not find function "A"
```

I've checked the contents of my `NAMESPACE` file is fine:

```
exportClasses(A)
import(methods)
```

So what's going wrong? Why isn't my class generator being exported?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759044/how-do-i-document-an-r-reference-class help?

Comment: @Andrie - not particularly, since that question talks at length about documentation tags, rather than why the `@export`/`@exportClass` tags are failing to export the class generator.

Comment: You need `@export` as well to export the generator.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you add `@export A` then the generator function `A` will be exported, too, e.g.

```
#' A class description
#'
#' @import methods
#' @export A
#' @exportClass A
A = setRefClass('A',
  fields=list(name='character', n='numeric'),
  methods=list(
    hello=function() {
      "A greeting"
      return(paste0('Hello, ', name))
    }
  )
)
```

Important: Don't forget to explicitly mention `A` in the export directive or it doesn't appear to work, unlike for functions.

Alternatively, as the class *is* being exported, you can still use the class via `new()`, e.g.

```
> a = new('A', name='Josh', n=12345)
> a$hello()
 [1] "Hello, Josh"
```

but it's easy to just add the export.